# Function that should return a single image to merge with others is returning an already-merged image

Tags: c#, .net

The code below is the entire contents of one function. The purpose of this function is to select a sprite, which is then returned and added to another image. I have it saving the file for debugging purposes because I wasn't getting the expected output. This function runs four times for each merged image. The first four files it saves are the expected output, but the 5th is the merged image.

I have searched my entire solution for other places where a file might be saved and there are none, although I used to have one that would output the extra file I'm seeing. I have tried restarting VS. Removing the line to save the file results in no files being output. The merged image is not added to any of the arrays used in this function and they do not exist anywhere in the solution, or even on my computer, until they are created by the program. I could be losing my mind, but I don't see any way that this function could select multiple images, and even if it could, it would simply overwrite the previously selected one.

```
Image sprite = null;

if(h ^ v)
{
    if(h)
    {
        //Selects an image from an array of images loaded from resources
        sprite = skins[layer][model.id].sprites[spriteIndex][Skin.HORIZONTAL];
    } else if(v)
    {
        sprite = skins[layer][model.id].sprites[spriteIndex][Skin.VERTICAL];
    }
} else if(h && v)
{
    if(d)
    {
        sprite = skins[layer][model.id].sprites[spriteIndex][Skin.SOLID];
    } else
    {
        sprite = skins[layer][model.id].sprites[spriteIndex][Skin.CONCAVE];
    }
} else
{
    sprite = skins[layer][model.id].sprites[spriteIndex][Skin.CONVEX];
}

sprite.Save("./output/" + saveCount + ".bmp");
saveCount++;
return sprite;
```

I would include more code, but most of the longer parts of my code are involved in this function.

Comment: I'm guessing that your "merge image" function modifies the pixels of `sprite` after it's returned from this function. If you don't explicitly make a copy, you're modifying the same object that's still stored in the array.

Comment: You say "The merged image is not added to any of the arrays used in this function and they do not exist anywhere in the solution". Are you changing any of the returned sprite images in your calling method? Then it changes as well in your array as an image is a reference type object. So your method only returns the reference to the image. Call 'return sprite.Clone();' if you want to return a copy of your sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Clone() when returning the sprite fixed the issue. I didn't realize that Graphics.FromImage() doesn't make a copy of the image.